# How to stop onLocationChanged from sending several locations per second? Or how to choose one?

Tags: android, multithreading, locationlistener

I am trying to make a tracking application for android, but the problem seems to be that when onLocationChanged is called it sends several locations in different threads, so i can't prevent it from sending 2-4 or even dozens of locations per second.

It seems like after a while of sending one every 20 seconds (as the MINTIME parameter specifies) the function sends multiple locations on the same second. I have tried to validate it so it only allows 1 to be sent, but it doesn't work since all the threads (i guess) manipulate all the variables at the same time and all locations end up showing as valid.

It doesn't always happen tho, some times the location listener will really only send 1 update every MINTIME, but it suddenly begins to send more and more until it sends 10+ per second.

So far i have tried using the synchronized keyword on the functions and using an atomicboolean to prevent more than 1 run at a time but nothing made a difference, and i had never worked with any of these things before so i don't know if im doing it wrong.

Here is the function that gets called to validate the coordinates

How can i ensure that each thread respects the variables and each location goes trough proper validation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public synchronized void  onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     proc_loc(location);
}

private synchronized void proc_loc(Location location) {
    if(run.compareAndSet(false,true)) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        String str;
        float lat = (float) latitude;
        float lon = (float) longitude;

        float dist = 0;
        String s_lat = "";
        String s_lon = "";
        String fecha = "";
        String l_time = "";

        String lati = "";
        String longi = "";

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("Camion", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Loci", null);
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            buffer.append("ID: " + c.getString(0) + "\n");
            buffer.append("l_time: " + c.getString(1) + "\n");
            buffer.append("lat: " + c.getString(2) + "\n\n");
            buffer.append("longi: " + c.getString(3) + "\n\n");
            buffer.append("fecha: " + c.getString(4) + "\n\n");

            l_time = c.getString(1);
            lati = c.getString(2);
            longi = c.getString(3);
        }

        valido = false;

        if (!lati.equals("-") && !lati.equals("")) {
            l = Long.parseLong(l_time);  // Prev stored time

            float t_lat = Float.valueOf(lati);
            float t_longi = Float.valueOf(longi);
            long c_t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            t_span = c_t- l;

            dist = distFrom(t_lat, t_longi, lat, lon);

            if (dist > 5 && dist < 10000 && (t_span > 60000)) {
                valido = true;

                if (!s_lat.equals("")) {
                    db.execSQL("UPDATE Loci SET l_time = '" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "', lat = '" + s_lat + "', longi ='" + s_lon + "', fecha = '" + fecha + "';");
                }
            }
        } else if (lati.equals("-")) {
            /****Remplazar default '-' por nuevas coord***/
            fecha = getDate(); //obt fecha
            s_lat = Float.toString(lat);
            s_lon = Float.toString(lon);

            db.execSQL("UPDATE Loci SET l_time = '" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "', lat = '" + s_lat + "', longi ='" + s_lon + "', fecha = '" + fecha + "';");

            valido = true;

            c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Loci", null);

            buffer.setLength(0);
            /*Si existen registros*/
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                buffer.append("ID: " + c.getString(0) + "\n");
                buffer.append("l_time: " + c.getString(1) + "\n");
                buffer.append("lat: " + c.getString(2) + "\n\n");
                buffer.append("longi: " + c.getString(3) + "\n\n");
                buffer.append("fecha: " + c.getString(4) + "\n\n");
            }
            str = "Remp default " + buffer.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (valido) {
            String s_latit = "";
            buffer.setLength(0);
                /*Si existen registros*/

            c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Loci", null);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                buffer.append("ID: " + c.getString(0) + "\n");
                buffer.append("l_time: " + c.getString(1) + "\n");
                buffer.append("lat: " + c.getString(2) + "\n\n");
                buffer.append("longi: " + c.getString(3) + "\n\n");
                buffer.append("fecha: " + c.getString(4) + "\n\n");
            }

            str = "VALIDO!!! \n D: " + Float.toString(dist) +"\n" + "\n" + Long.toString(l)+ "\n" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "\n" + Long.toString(t_span) + "\n" + "\n" + buffer.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            Runnable r = new SendUDP(9001, lat, lon);
            new Thread(r).start();
            cont++;
        }
        valido = false;
        run.set(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old Location API. The new one uses a request builder. Take a look at the tutorial [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android).

Also, note that you can ask for the last known location. If that is sufficient, you don't even have to setup the listener.

If you do go into the callback sequence, you simply cacnel the listener when you have a location that you are satisfied with.

Comment: Thanks ill check out the new tutorial.

The problem is that i need the locations sent in real time every minute or so, and there will almost never be an user monitoring the cellphone. 

So i guess i do need a listener for this case?

Comment: It's always a good idea to post what you want to do, then explain what your problem is, otherwise we don't know what to recommend. Your question says you can't figure out how to tell it to stop sending updates. If there's no user, why do you have to update every few minutes? maybe you should look at significant change notifications..

Comment: I mean i cant stop it from sending updates in the sense that i only need 1 per minute, but it sends more when the MINTIME in requestlocationupdates is reached. Then it sends 2-10 location in the same second and stops for another MINTIME.

So what i need is either stop it from sending temporarily or a way to allow the function to validate all the locations that it sends in many threads.

The units will be monitored on a map on the web, so we do need constant updates. The function i posted does call to a distance calcuating function to decide whether to send it
Sorry if i wasn't specific enough.